# Do respond to js and executing a js.erb file changes the csrf token in rails?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, csrf

I have a navigation bar which have few tab like users,roles,etc
All the tabs use link_to with remote true.
Hence when I click on any of the tab an ajax call is made to index action of that controller.
So suppose i click on users index action of controller is called which respond to that with index.js.erb. In that js.erb file I am doing an escape javascript and loading the partial to a div.

I am using inline editing to edit the users list i got or delete them.

The problem i am facing is that all the post action requires a csrf token and i have already included it in the application layout.

However whenever i try to delete or edit a record I get csrf token invalid.

What i figured out is the csrf token is changed whenever i do the js.erb call.

Can some body help me to figure out whats the best possible way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this :

```
<%= form_for @some_model, remote: true, authenticity_token: true do |f| %>     
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'click_me', some_path, remote: true, authenticity_token: true %>
```

Now, the forms won't render the CSRF token until specified explicitly. Try this.